# In ios7, UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton is divided into two different accessory buttons

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview

[image: ios7 UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton] [image: ios6 UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton]

Check mark represents the selected row at that time, left image is of iOS7 simulator and right is of iOS6 simulator.

The concern is `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton in iOS7 has two parts, one part with right arrow accessory and other is the clickable "i" button rather than iOS6.`
Is it a standard behaviour or am I doing something wrong, if it is standard then what should be the correct way of handling UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton in iOS7?

Comment: Note that width of ios7 is larger than ios6, check with of both in run-time and see what you get.

Comment: Show some code for how you are configuring / laying out your cell contents.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

mahboudz is correct in that the behaviours are now differentiated.

If you set only the DetailButton then in iOS7 you will see the (i) as a tap-able accessory button. But in iOS6 you won't see anything. So popping a detail view using `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` using SDK7.0 doesn't work on an iOS6 device as no accessory gets displayed.

Using the reverse config has similar issues, but you would be using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` instead.

The work around I found was to apply a similar approach to the dealing with the extendedLayouts in iOS7.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    cell.accessoryType =  UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType =  UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
}
```

So in iOS7 I use the DetailButton only and in pre-iOS7 versions I use the `DetailDiscloureButton`.

Answer (score 8):

This is the correct behavior. In iOS 7, you show both the "detail button" and the "disclosure indicator" using `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`.

If you'd only like the "i" button, you'd use `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton` and if you'd only like the "disclosure indicator, you'd use  `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`.

Comment: It's not as simple as that. UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton does not track your finger like UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton did.